# My sticky footer displays weirdly on bigger or smaller screens, how do I make these elements to scale?

Tags: html, css

The elements I am reffering to are the footer links here: http://individual.utoronto.ca/andrewlouis

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Andrew Louis' Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jqueryscript.js"></script>

<body>

    <h2>Andrew Louis</h2>

    <div class="centered">
        Coming Soon.
        <div id = "subheading">
            <a href="http://andrewlouis.posterous.com">Click here to go to my blog in the meantime.</a>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#footer {position:relative;}

#heading{
    font-family:'Lobster1.3Regular';
    color:#D04D21;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:80px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.nav_wrapper{
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
     bottom:-500px; ; left:0px;
}

#list_orientation li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;

}
#list_orientation li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:50px;
    height:50px;width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
```

Comment: Post code, don't just post a link....

Comment: Sorry just added relevant code!

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be line breaking as they are wider than the page wrap. You could give the elements smaller width and height values with media queries?

Comment: I doubt it, the elements do fit from the values I gave... If you want, you can refer to the code I posted above.